# Jetpack Compose not updating / recomposing Flow List Values from Room DB when i react a message room db updated

Tags: android, android-room

i'm trying to show a List of Items in my Android App. I'm using Jetpack Compose, Flows and RoomDB.

When launching the Activity all Items are shown without any problems, the Flow get's items collected and they are displayed.

But when I change some properties of the Item in the Database, the changes are not displayed.
When I look at the Database Inspector, the value is changed in the database

```
val messages: StateFlow<List<Message>> = _messages

    init {
        getMessages(roomId = room.roomId)
    }

    private fun getMessages(roomId: Long) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
                chatWindowRepository.getMessages(roomId)
                    .collect {
                        _messages.emit(it)
       }
     }
    }

    @Update
    suspend fun reactMessage(message: Message)
    @Query("Select * From Message where roomId =:roomId order by cd desc")
    fun getAllMessage(roomId: Long): Flow<List<Message>>

    val list = vm.messages.collectAsState()
```

Comment: Hey @Ain Soft, Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Can you please include some piece of code that you tried already and whatever the things that you done. It will give clarity to understand your problem.

Comment: HI Abhinav Suman thanks for your response

Comment: the issue is _message.emit(it) only once when i navigate to screen but when i react a message collect lambda returns with updated list but _message.emit not emitting updated list